# if we know eigenvector of a matrix, what will be eigenvector for cube of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can I verify $(1,- {1 \over 2},0)$ is an eigenvector of M³?

I can consider a diagonal matrix with all diagonal entries $⁻3$, or I can consider a general diagonal matrix.

But my question is how I can shortly and quickly have an idea about eigenvector for M³?

[image]

Comment: Hint: You can show by induction that if $M\mathbf{v} = \lambda \mathbf{v}$, then $M^k \mathbf{v} = \lambda^k \mathbf{v}$ for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

Comment: i am facing a problem on stackexchange, anything you comment only words of english are visible, mathematical portion come in complicated way like in C language many keywords are there.

Comment: howvi can fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Mv=3v\implies M(-\frac12v)=-\frac32v\implies M^3(-\frac12v)=-\frac{27}2v$.  So we get $-\frac{27}2\begin{pmatrix}-2\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}27\\-\frac{27}2\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the matrix $M$ as a linear operator.  What happens when you apply $M$ three times to an eigenvector?  Do it one step at a time and I think the answer will jump out at you.

Comment: see , again i have to think a linear operator which satisfy these conditions